# Regex express to find a number in a string in ruby

Tags: ruby

'xyz_1_yx'
'xyz-1-yx'

I have tried to find the correct regex expression to extract 1

```
  def find_number(image_basename)
    startIndex= 1
    endIndex= 10

    (startIndex..endIndex).each do |n|
      return n if /\b-|_#{n}-|_\b/.match(image_basename)
    end
    nil
  end
```

2.5.0 :376 > find_number('xyz_1_yx')
 => nil

Comment: with this express ipad129_portait' returns 129 instead of nil

Answer (score 0):

```
b
=> "asdas-12-asd" 
b.scan(/([A-z]*)(_{1}|-{1})(\d*)(_{1}|-{1})([A-z]*)/)
=> [["asdas", "-", "12", "-", "asd"]]
```

**UPDATE**

here it is  with noncapturing group

```
b.scan(/(?:[A-z]*)(?:_{1}|-{1})(\d*)(?:_{1}|-{1})(?:[A-z]*)/)
 => [["12"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = 'xyz_1_y1x'
```

If you want the first `'1'`,

```
r = /1/
str[r]
  #=> "1"
```

which uses the method [String#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D). Alternatively:

```
str.each_char.find { |c| c == '1' }
  #=> `'1'`
```

If you want all `'1'`'s, use [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-scan):

```
str.scan r
  #=> ["1", "1"]
```

Note that `str[r]` is equivalent to determining whether the string contains one or more `'1'`'s and `str.scan(r)` tells us nothing more than the number of `'1'` that are contained in the string.

If you want to extract any digit, change the regular expression: `r = /\d/`.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your question, you want the characters between `-` or `_`. If that's the case you can simply do

```
str = 'xyz_1_yx'
str.split(/[-,_]/)[1] 
#=> '1'

str = 'xyz-129-yx'
str.split(/[-,_]/)[1] 
#=> '129'
```